# slicing multindex rows -- 'cannot do label indexing'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two levels of multindex rows.  The levels of are type: `<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>` and `<class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>`

```
                                 px_settlement contract_code
assessment_date contract_serial                             
2014-01-02      201402                  18.640           g14
                201403                  17.530           h14
                201404                  16.600           j14
                201405                  15.900           k14
                201406                  16.100           m14
                201407                  16.200           n14
                201408                  15.210           q14
                201409                  15.210           u14
                201410                  15.210           v14
                201411                  15.210           x14
```

I'm trying to get a slice of 'all rows where contract_serial = 201410' for example.

I've tried several variations of `.loc`

```
jkm_df.loc[:, 201506]

TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [201506] of <class 'int'>
```

also

```
jkm_df.loc[(:, 201506), :]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's the correct way to subselect this multiindex by assessment_date or contract_serial?

Comment: `idx = pd.IndexSlice; df.loc[idx[:, 201410], :]`

Comment: @coldspeed  wow, fast, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (jkm_df.xs(201406, level=1))
                 px_settlement contract_code
assessment_date                             
2014-01-02                16.1           m14
```

Also if necessary both levels use parameter `drop_level=False`:

```
print (jkm_df.xs(201406, level=1, drop_level=False))
                                 px_settlement contract_code
assessment_date contract_serial                             
2014-01-02      201406                    16.1           m14
```

Solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (jkm_df.loc(axis=0)[:, 201406])
                                 px_settlement contract_code
assessment_date contract_serial                             
2014-01-02      201406                    16.1           m14
```

Another solution with [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
print (jkm_df.loc[(slice(None), 201406), :])
                                 px_settlement contract_code
assessment_date contract_serial                             
2014-01-02      201406                    16.1           m14
```

Comment: I'm going to add IndexSlice as an answer, is that fine?

Comment: It is up to you.

Comment: Cheers, happy holidays!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I signed it back to dupe, but thank you.

Comment: Okay, it was up to you. I deleted my answer as well. Keep in mind that, my problem with you is that you sometimes answer questions that are obvious duplicates (not just _any_ duplicates) You've answered thousands of pandas questions, so you should be aware when you are writing the same thing. I don't think I'm the boss of anybody, my ego isn't _that_ inflated. Also, please don't play the victim card because you know you've made mistakes in the past, that's not up for discussion. I've deleted my answer, because you've made the noble decision to not post your answer too. Let's move on from this.

Comment: And yes, I slipped this time, and did something I'd usually chide others for doing. My apologies for that. But I haven't changed my principles about answering duplicates, and don't intend to. I will continue to close questions if they are obvious dupes lacking any research effort, and will not answer questions that are of such abysmal quality that they don't deserve to be answered. We'd get along a lot better if you made an effort to do the same. :p I like answering questions for points just like you, but I also want to make sure I don't harm the site by my actions.

Comment: To drive home my point, go to [this link](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/481662/dupe-hammer-usage-per-user) and run the SEDE query. You'll see I have closed over 600 questions, so you can understand I have closed a _lot_ of questions in my 6-7 months on StackOverflow. I've told you I'm not here to persecute you, I am just acting in line with what's best for the site.

Comment: Thank you. I think the best is close all obvious dupes, I completely agree with you. And I forget for last times too, please give me know if some problem with me in future.  And small present for you as white flag, +5.

Comment: Returned, please keep me in check if I make mistakes as well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`xs` is good for retrieving scalar values. Another solution (offering slightly more flexibility) is using `pd.IndexSlice` + `loc`.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 201410], :]

                                 px_settlement contract_code
assessment_date contract_serial                             
2014-01-02      201406                    16.1           m14
```